# Why does Node evaluate all exports when it is importing from an ES module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, commonjs

I am the maintainer of an extremely large (CommonJS) JavaScript package. The JavaScript package is split into subparts, each of which are exported as a symbol from the top-level `index.js` file.

In TypeScript, this looks like:

```
export * as submodule1 from './submodule1';
export * as submodule2 from './submodule2';
// etc
```

The library is in fact so large that importing represents a noticeable performance hit. In particular, a customer doesn't necessarily want to use all submodules in every program, but because of the import style all files of all submodules end up being `require()`d at module load time.

### Lazy loading

Because I wrote it, I know that loading the library does not have any side-effects. It occurred to me that I can delay loading the submodules until they are actually accessed by the user.

I would turn the above into:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, 'submodule1', {
  get: () => require('./submodule1'),
});
```

Which makes it so `submodule1/index.js` and its entire subtree is only loaded if the user actually accesses the `submodule1` symbol.

(Note: the *actual* syntax of what I'm emitting is slightly different than the above, because Node will not support importing the library above from an ES module... but the code above represents in essence what I'm trying to achieve).

### Eager ESM loading

The above trick works great when the library is being loaded from CommonJS, but it doesn't work at all when the library is being loaded from ESM. It looks like Node is accessing all module members as soon as a library is loaded.

I conducted a small experiment to prove this:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  node_modules/lazylib/index.js

// Trickery necessary to make the CJS exports recognized from an ESM context
exports.someSymbol = void 0;
Object.defineProperty(exports, 's' + 'omeSymbol', {
    get: () => {
        // Proof that the code is being evaluated
        console.log('evaluated');
        return 42;
    },
});


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  test.js
const ll = require('lazylib')

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  test.mjs
import * as ll from 'lazylib';
```

Now when I run these:

```bash
$ node test.js
                # nothing here, as expected

$ node test.mjs
evaluated       # <--- this is unexpected!
```

So it seems that Node will eagerly evaluate all symbols exported from a module as it is loading it. Potentially this only happens when loading a CJS module, but there's no way for me to tell the difference as this lazy loading behavior cannot be emulated using ESM.

Why is this happening? And is there anything I can do about it? (If your reaction would be to say: "your package shouldn't be so big that load time becomes a problem, the correct solution is to split it up", then rest assured I am aware, but a number of factors necessitate what we have right now. I am really only looking for an answer to my question.)

Comment: With ESM dynamic loading is Promise based, so you would need to refactor slightly here and then use `import()` variant.   IOW: require in nodejs is synchronous, and that's none standard.

Comment: "*your package shouldn't be so big that load time becomes a problem, the correct solution is to split it up*" - the alternative to splitting it up is to ask the customer to use a bundler (or other build tool) that supports treeshaking, i.e. omitting the things that are not imported anywhere.

Comment: "*Why is this happening?*" - try putting a `debugger` statement in your getter. My guess is that it's trying to freeze your exports by copying them over to a ES module namespace object that is read-only and non-extensible.

Comment: Another even more simpler option is slowly start and get your consumers to use `import * as someModule1 from "mylib/someModule1"` instead of `import {someModule1} from "mylib"`,  The benefit here is that it increases performance for both ESM & CommonJS without any jiggery pokery.

Comment: Cheers @Bergi! So obvious, why didn't I think of it, but that helped. I still don't know "why" it happens, but at least I now know why it happens, if that makes sense 

Comment: @rix0rrr Can you [edit] your question (or even [post an answer](/help/self-answer)) with the result of your investigation? What code did you find that accesses the properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that all getters are being read, is because the ESM importer iterates over all exports to call a method called `this.setExport()`:

```
    for (const exportName of exportNames) {
      if (!ObjectPrototypeHasOwnProperty(exports, exportName) ||
          exportName === 'default') {
        continue;
      }
      // We might trigger a getter -> dont fail.
      let value;
      try {
        value = exports[exportName];
      } catch {
        // Continue regardless of error.
      }
      this.setExport(exportName, value);
    }
```

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/1d220b55ac397f15758e83d1143789608e3fca4a/lib/internal/modules/esm/translators.js#L301C32-L301C32

I'm still not sure about the motivation, but this is the code in Node.js as currently written.

Comment: `this.setExport` is a call to the native [`ModuleWrap::SetSyntheticExport`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/src/module_wrap.cc) C++ method which calls some V8 API - all this appears to be necessary for constructing a module. I doubt a module record can be built where the export is a getter that dynamically accesses the cjs exports object.